# How to connect to keosd?

Tags: cleos

I am trying to deploy a contract to the jungle testnet. I get the following error -

> cleos wallet import -n trevor5 5KcFCgZiixiZ69dyA5u3......RBQtZ
>   "/usr/local/bin/keosd" launched Unable to connect to keosd, if keosd
>   is running please kill the process and try again.
>   ~/Projects/EOS/eos/build/programs/keosd$

I kill keosd and then try again. I get the same error message and keosd seems to startup again.

Has anyone any idea how to solve this?

A few comments to give more details following the response to my question -

config.ini -

```
# The local IP and port to listen for incoming http connections; set blank to disable. (eosio::http_plugin)
http-server-address = 127.0.0.1:8888

# The local IP and port to listen for incoming https connections; leave blank to disable. (eosio::http_plugin)
# https-server-address = 

# Filename with the certificate chain to present on https connections. PEM format. Required for https. (eosio::http_plugin)
# https-certificate-chain-file = 

# Filename with https private key in PEM format. Required for https (eosio::http_plugin)
# https-private-key-file = 

# Specify the Access-Control-Allow-Origin to be returned on each request. (eosio::http_plugin)
# access-control-allow-origin = 

# Specify the Access-Control-Allow-Headers to be returned on each request. (eosio::http_plugin)
# access-control-allow-headers = 

# Specify the Access-Control-Max-Age to be returned on each request. (eosio::http_plugin)
# access-control-max-age = 

# Specify if Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true should be returned on each request. (eosio::http_plugin)
access-control-allow-credentials = false

# The maximum body size in bytes allowed for incoming RPC requests (eosio::http_plugin)
max-body-size = 1048576

# Append the error log to HTTP responses (eosio::http_plugin)
verbose-http-errors = false

# If set to false, then any incoming "Host" header is considered valid (eosio::http_plugin)
http-validate-host = 1

# Additionaly acceptable values for the "Host" header of incoming HTTP requests, can be specified multiple times.  Includes http/s_server_address by default. (eosio::http_plugin)
# http-alias = 

# The path of the wallet files (absolute path or relative to application data dir) (eosio::wallet_plugin)
wallet-dir = "."

# Timeout for unlocked wallet in seconds (default 900 (15 minutes)). Wallets will automatically lock after specified number of seconds of inactivity. Activity is defined as any wallet command e.g. list-wallets. (eosio::wallet_plugin)
unlock-timeout = 900

# Plugin(s) to enable, may be specified multiple times
# plugin =
```

I get the keosd apparently seeking to listen on 8900 which is different to the port in config.ini.

```
cleos wallet import -n trevor5 5KcFCgZiixiZ69dyA5u39SG...8drWEXrRBQtZ
"/usr/local/bin/keosd" launched
Unable to connect to keosd, if keosd is running please kill the process and try again.
~/Projects/EOS/eos$ ps aux | grep keosd
satoshimaca       1180   0.0  0.0  4267752    764 s000  R+   10:05am   0:00.00 grep keosd
satoshimaca       1170   0.0  0.1  4291748   6768 s000  S    10:04am   0:00.02 /usr/local/bin/keosd --http-server-address=::1:8900
~/Projects/EOS/eos$
```

Here is my filelist -

```
~/Projects/EOS/eos$ ls
CMakeLists.txt      debian          programs
CMakeModules        docs            scripts
Docker          eos.doxygen.in      testnet.md
HEADER          eosio_build.sh      testnet.template
LICENSE.txt     externals       tests
README.md       images          tools
build           libraries       tutorials
contracts       plugins         unittests
~/Projects/EOS/eos$
```

The config.ini file is actually under

```
    3 satoshimaca  staff        96 15 Jul 16:46 eosio-wallet
drwxr-xr-x    6 satoshimaca  staff       192 15 Jul 12:39 Projects
```

I am unsure if that makes any different to cleos finding it.

I tried various versions of the following but they all state the same error as I posted originally -

> cleos wallet --wallet-url TEXT=http://127.0.0.1:8888/ import -n
>   trevor5 5KcFCgZiixiZ69dyA5u39SGWg4........WEXrRBQtZ

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling with the same. The issue is that `cleos` tries to start `keosd` automatically but it doesn't seem to use the `keosd` `config.ini` file located in `~/eosio-wallet` when doing so. I've resorted to just running `keosd` separately and letting `cleos` connect to the one I started manually.

In my `~/eosio-wallets/config.ini` file I have the following:

```
# The local IP and port to listen for incoming http connections; set blank to disable. (eosio::http_plugin)
http-server-address = localhost:8900
```

This `localhost:8900` is the address where `cleos` tries to find `keosd` by default, which saves you from having to always type `--wallet-url <something>`.

Then I start `keosd` by just running it directly as in `./keosd` or simply `keosd` if you added it to your `PATH` or created an alias for it. This way it will actually use the `http-server-address` specified in the config file.

After it starts, you can then use `cleos` and it won't bother starting the `keosd` process because it will find the one that is already running:

```
cleos wallet import -n trevor5 5KcFCgZiixiZ69dyA5u39SG...8drWEXrRBQtZ
```

This command should now work, and you don't need to specify the wallet address or anything else.
Hope it helps!

Comment: I will test this more. I tried what you said and the old error vanishes but new ones show up. I will test more and then post the outcomes. Thanks.

Comment: No problem! By the way, make sure you kill all the other `keosd` processes that might have been left running after being started by `cleos`. I'm curious about what errors you're getting now!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have your wallet's address specified in keosd's config.ini, then you will need to specify it when launching the cleos command. To find the config.ini go `sudo find / -name config.ini` and look for the `~/eosio-wallet/config.ini` directory.

[image]

To do this from cleos without needing to edit the config.ini, simply add the following flag to cleos:

```
--wallet-url TEXT=http://localhost:8900/
                              the http/https URL where keosd is running
```

You can see your keosd address when you launch keosd:

[image]

Comment: I added a few more details in the original question via an edit. The config.ini does exist but the port stated is different to the listening one in the process. I put in more details about the file structure. I tried various combinations of manually stating the url but they returned the same error. The same error happens with cleos wallet list too.